# Setting up constraints programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have some images set programmatically but the images aren't reaching the full width of the screen. Maybe because the images aren't that big? Is there a way I can get my 3 images to be more constrained to the right side of the screen(See attached image)?

If add `constant: 40` to the constraint it adjusts the width for the bigger screen size but then it makes it wider than the screen for a smaller screen size

This is how I have my images set up:

```
// creating an image
private lazy var backgroundImage: UIImageView = {
        let backgroundImage = UIImageView()
        backgroundImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return backgroundImage
}()
```

```
// setting up cosntraints for image
private func setupConstraints(){
        let margins = layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            backgroundImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor),
            backgroundImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor),
            backgroundImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor),
            backgroundImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor)
        ])
}
```

[viewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gntD.png)

Comment: Set contentMode to scaleAspectFill or scaleAspectFit

Comment: Use the [debug view hierarchy](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev4dfdedb7a) tool to figure out what the size of the image view is. That will help you identify whether the problem is the size of the image view, the size of the superview, the content mode, etc. That will eliminate the guesswork.

Comment: I'd bet that it's because you are initializing these variables before the screen actually loads. Where are you calling these functions? If it's within a reusable cell, I would try settings the size during cellForItemAt method.